# In java how to construct an array when we know only component class

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create a an array of object with only class of object :

```
Class<?> klass = ...;

Constructor< ? > constructor = klass.getConstructor();

Object inst = constructor.newInstance(); // create an object with default constructor
```

Is it possible to do something like this ?

```
Object table = constructor.newInstanceTable(size)
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an array of instances of class `klass`?

Comment: can you be a little bit more clear about what is your requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `java.lang.reflect.Array` class:

```
Object array = Array.newInstance(klass, size);
```

Comment: The complete question is described here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51771749/how-to-automatically-generate-initial-multi-dimensional-field-values-in-java

Answer (score 1):

As per [Creating New Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/arrayInstance.html) tutorial use the methods on [`java.lang.reflect.Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html):

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(cName);
Object o = Array.newInstance(c, n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    String v = cVals[i];
    Constructor ctor = c.getConstructor(String.class);
    Object val = ctor.newInstance(v);
    Array.set(o, i, val);
}
```